# Configuration aarch64-apple-darwin supported by gmp, mpfr and mpc but not by gcc-5.2.0

Tags: ios, gcc, gmp, arm64

I am under mac OSX, using apple's `clang`/`clang++` and am cross building various libraries for iOS8.4. The main goal is to cross build `gcc-5.2.0` for iOS8.4, so that I have to build at least `gmp`, `mpfr` and `mpc`.

I built `gmp` (last snapshot at the time this question is written) as follows :

```
../configure --prefix=/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/gmp-6.1.0/ CC="clang -fembed-bitcode -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -Wno-error -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -mios-version-min=8.4 -no-integrated-as -arch arm64 -target arm64-apple-darwin" CPP="clang -E" CPPFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -Wno-error -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -mios-version-min=8.4 -no-integrated-as -arch arm64 -target arm64-apple-darwin" --host=aarch64-apple-darwin --disable-assembly --enable-static --disable-shared
make -j 4
sudo make install
```

I built `mpfr-3.1.3` as follows :

```
../configure --prefix=/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/mpfr-3.1.3 CC="clang -fembed-bitcode -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -Wno-error -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -mios-version-min=8.4 -no-integrated-as -arch arm64 -target arm64-apple-darwin" CPP="clang -E" CPPFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -Wno-error -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -mios-version-min=8.4 -no-integrated-as -arch arm64 -target arm64-apple-darwin" --with-gmp=/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/gmp-6.1.0/ --host=aarch64-apple-darwin --disable-assembly --enable-static --disable-shared
make -j 4
sudo make install
```

and `mpc-1.0.3` as follows :

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/gmp-6.1.0/lib/:/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/mpfr-3.1.3/lib/ ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/mpc-1.0.3 CC="clang -fembed-bitcode -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -Wno-error -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -mios-version-min=8.4 -no-integrated-as -arch arm64 -target arm64-apple-darwin" CPP="clang -E" CPPFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -Wno-error -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -mios-version-min=8.4 -no-integrated-as -arch arm64 -target arm64-apple-darwin" --with-gmp=/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/gmp-6.1.0/ --with-mpfr=/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/mpfr-3.1.3/ --host=aarch64-apple-darwin --disable-assembly --enable-static --disable-shared
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/gmp-6.1.0/lib/:/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/mpfr-3.1.3/lib/ make -j 4
sudo make install
```

Now, I am trying to build `gcc-5.2.0`as follows :

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/gmp-6.1.0/lib/:/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/mpfr-3.1.3/lib/:/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/mpc-1.0.3/lib/ ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/gcc-5.2.0 CC="clang -fembed-bitcode -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -Wno-error -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -mios-version-min=8.4 -no-integrated-as -arch arm64 -target arm64-apple-darwin" CPP="clang -E" CPPFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -Wno-error -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -mios-version-min=8.4 -no-integrated-as -arch arm64 -target arm64-apple-darwin" --enable-checking=release --with-gmp=/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/gmp-6.1.0/ --with-mpfr=/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/mpfr-3.1.3/ --with-mpc=/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/mpc-1.0.3/ --host=aarch64-apple-darwin --disable-assembly --enable-static --disable-shared
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/gmp-6.1.0/lib/:/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/mpfr-3.1.3/lib/:/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/mpc-1.0.3/lib/ make -j 4
```

and have `Configuration aarch64-apple-darwin not supported`. Too bad.

What can I do ? This configuration is supported by `gmp`, `mpfr` and `mpc` but not by `gcc-5.2.0`. Is there another close configuration that I could use instead ? Like arm*-none-* or aarch64-none-* ?

*Remark.* I tried `armv7` instead of `arm64` and `aarch64`, same result : `Configuration armv7-apple-darwin not supported`...

Comment: You want to run a compiler under iOS?

Comment: @trojanfoe Indeed. (I already cross-built llvm+clang for iOS8.4, so that I have working llvm+clang on iOS8.4, but now I need gcc-5.2.0.)